# Mockito - Set a flag when a void method has been called

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a problem with Mockito. I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Foo<T> {
   BaseView mView;

   public Foo(BaseView view) {
      mView = view;
   }

   public void onResponse(T data) {
      mView.setup(data);
   }

   public void onError(int error) {
      mView.displayError(error);
   }
}
```

ok, so What I want to do?

This is the test flow I'm wanting to do for Foo,

Mock a `BaseView` for `Foo`.
If `Foo onResponse` error has been called, return true.
If `Foo onError` has been called, return false.

This is what I tried already:

```
   public class BasePresenterCompatTest<T extends BasePresenterCompat> {
   private Boolean setupCalled;

   public void TestPresenterCall(BasePresenterCompat mPresenter) throws Exception {
       Mockito.doAnswer(new TrueAnswer()).when(Mockito.mock(mPresenter.getClass())).onResponse(Mockito.any());
       Mockito.doAnswer(new FalseAnswer()).when(Mockito.mock(mPresenter.getClass())).onError(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
       Assert.assertEquals(true, setupCalled);
   }

   class TrueAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {
       @Override
       public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
           return setupCalled = true;
       }
   }

   class FalseAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {
       @Override
       public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
           return setupCalled = false;
       }
   }
 }
```

Is the Answer interface implementation a good approach? Because I tried debugging the test and it never enters to the Answer classes answer method, what am I missing?

O I forgot to add, the exception I'm getting with my method above is:

```
      Wanted but not invoked.
     Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what exactly you want to test in terms of Foo's behaviour. 
When I look at Foo, there's only two things to test: mViews.setup is called onResponse and mView.displayError is called onError. You're doing none of that, what are you trying to do with mPresenter.getClass?

Comment: What Im trying is this, mPresenter is an Instance of a class called BasePresenter in the project, it calls a Retrofit Client with a Callback, the callback sends to this BasePresenter data in "onResponse" method or a @StringRes integer in "onError".

I want to test: if onResponse method has been called, report true, if onError was called, report false instead.

Comment: But both of those methods are void and do not return anything, how can they return true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to test this scenario ...

> mPresenter is an Instance of a class called BasePresenter in the project, it calls a Retrofit Client with a Callback, the callback sends to this BasePresenter data in "onResponse" method or a @StringRes integer in "onError".

... is to mock whatever the callback is invoked on and to [verify](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification) that the correct invocations are made on that mock.

For example:

```
@Test
public void testMockInvocation() {
    BaseView baseView = Mockito.mock(BaseView.class);

    Foo<String> foo = new Foo(baseView);

    String input = "some input";
    foo.onResponse(input);

    Mockito.verify(baseView).setup(input);

    int error = 1;
    foo.onError(error);

    Mockito.verify(baseView).displayError(error);
}
```

Since, the `setup` and `displayError` methods are typed `void` they cannot return anything so I suspect this ...

> If Foo onResponse error has been called, return true. If Foo onError has been called, return false.

... refers to an idea about how your test can prove/verify that the correct methods were called on the `baseView`. If so, then you can use `Mockito.verify()` (as shown in the example above) to do this.

Comment: Thaks for the answer, I tried before with Mockito.when but dont with verify on the view. I'll try this. thank you.